# kaggle kernel can't install python package

Tags: pip, kaggle

I'm a kaggle kernel beginner, and I want to use kaggle kernal's free GPU to learn tensorflow 2.0, but I can't install tensorflow 2.0 by `!pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is I not enable the kaggle kernel internet.
so the detail solution is:

kernel settings > internet > on

and it works!